# Regular expression to parse AT command response

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a return message from AT command response.

This is the input:

> AT+CUSD=1,"*124#",15
>
> OK
>
> +CUSD: 2,"00302220100 Your main balance is 10K, valid until 23/10/2015. For more balance details, please send BAL to 1"

My expected result is:

> 00302220100 Your main balance is 10K, valid until 23/10/2015. For more balance details, please send BAL to 1

Here is my code:

```
    private string ParseMessages_ChkCredit(string input)
    {
        string messages = "";
        Regex r = new Regex("\\AT+CUSD: (\\d+),\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(input);
        while (m.Success)
        {
            messages = m.Groups[2].Value.ToString();
            break;
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

The regular expression does not match. Please kindly help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Think you missed the trailing `"` from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=AT\+[\s\S]*?CUSD:[^"]*")[^"]*
```

You can make use `variable lookbehind`.[See demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3dAT%5c%2b%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3fCUSD%3a%5b%5e%22%5d*%22)%5b%5e%22%5d*&i=AT%2bCUSD%3d1%2c%22*124%23%22%2c15%0d%0a%0d%0aOK%0d%0a%0d%0a%2bCUSD%3a+2%2c%2200302220100+Your+main+balance+is+10K%2c+valid+until+23%2f10%2f2015.+For+more+balance+details%2c+please+send+BAL+to+1)

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=AT\+[\s\S]*?CUSD:[^""]*"")[^""]*";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"AT+CUSD=1,""*124#"",15" + "\n" + @"OK" + "\n\n" + @"+CUSD: 2,""00302220100 Your main balance is 10K, valid until 23/10/2015. For more balance details, please send BAL to 1""" + "\n";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=\+CUSD\: 2,\")(.+)
```

#### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL2mL4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=\+CUSD:\s+2,")[^"]+
```

In C#, declare as:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\+CUSD:\s+2,"")[^""]+");
```

The `(?<=\+CUSD:\s+2,")` look-behind will check the right position in the string, and the expected output will reside in the `m.Value`.

Here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%2BCUSD%3A%5Cs%2B2%2C%22)%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=AT%2BCUSD%3D1%2C%22*124%23%22%2C15%0D%0A%0D%0AOK%0D%0A%0D%0A%2BCUSD%3A%202%2C%2200302220100%20Your%20main%20balance%20is%2010K%2C%20valid%20until%2023%2F10%2F2015.%20For%20more%20balance%20details%2C%20please%20send%20BAL%20to%201)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `AT` from your regular expression.

Try `\+CUSD: (\d+),"(.*?)"`

```
new Regex("\\+CUSD: (\\d+),\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```